# Using KDE Connect through Internet

Tags: internet, kde, kde5, kde-connect

As far as I know, Connect requires to have both PC and smartphone to be in same sub-network. But this is very disapointing for me. Because I have unlimited mobile internet and never use wi-fi at my home.

I'm really new with KDE Connect and I really like it. Does anybody knows if it's possible to use it through Internet?

I also have a dinamic IP adress on my router but I think that I can set up port forwarding and Dynamic-DNS.

Comment: I tried to set up dynamic dns and unfortunately, my provider blocks incoming traffic due specific network configuration.

Comment: I’d advise against this. How do you intend to keep your systems secure if they’re exposed to the public internet? Get an app for your phone that automatically turns on WiFi when you’re home and turn it off when you leave. Prolongs your battery life as a bonus.

Comment: @Aeyoun yes, it is. But I want to make some proof of the concept at this point, not an everyday solution. Anyway, my Internet provider doesn't allow such things, so I setup small private VPN server in internet and connect into it from smartphone and PC. And it is actually working. But it is still needs a lot of setup and tune to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to use a VPN. There are some [instructions on using OpenVPN](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#Running_KDE_Connect_over_OpenVPN), but it should be possible to achieve with other VPN technologies as well.